# How to loop through 2 variables in ggplot2 using lapply

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I got two parameters in my ggplot2 and want to create a list object for all the plots.
Somehow it gives me an error

```
data = data.frame(date = rep(seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), 
                                 as.Date('2020-01-07'),length.out =7),2), 
                             METRIC_NAME = rep(c('a','b','c','d','e','f','g'),2), 
                             METRIC_VALUE = seq(1,14,1), DIMENSION = rep(c('A','B'),7))
                  all_dimensions = unique(data$DIMENSION)
                  all_metric = unique(data$METRIC_NAME)
                  
                  
                  
                  plot_function = function(x,y){
                    p = ggplot(subset(data, METRIC_NAME == x & DIMENSION == y),
                               aes(x = DATE, y = METRIC_VALUE,
                                   color = DIMENSION_VALUE))+ geom_line() + 
                      scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("week"),
                                   labels = date_format("%d-%b"),
                                   minor_breaks = date_breaks("1 day"))+
                      facet_wrap(dim~., scales = 'free')
                    return (p)}
                  
                  
                  lapply(all_metric, function(x){lapply(all_dimensions, 
                                                        function(y)plot(x,y))} )
```

The error is

```
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
```

Comment: just updated the question

Comment: Assuming you are using all the correct variable names in the `ggplot` code, your function is called `plot_function` whereas you are calling `plot` in `lapply`.

Comment: ahhh you are right!!! good catch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the dataset for each combination of group and use `map` to apply the plot function to each group.

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  group_split(DIMENSION, METRIC_NAME) %>%
  map(function(x){
      ggplot(x,aes(x = date, y = METRIC_VALUE, 
                   color = DIMENSION_VALUE))+ geom_line() + 
        scale_x_date(breaks = date_breaks("week"),
                     labels = date_format("%d-%b"),
                     minor_breaks = date_breaks("1 day"))+
        facet_wrap(DIMENSION~., scales = 'free')
}) -> list_plots

list_plots
```